# Android UX question regarding state of a selection screen

Tags: mobile, selection

In an Android app I have a screen where the user can select some parameters for a search. Among those parameters is a location. The pre-selection is `Berlin`. The user can click on a button (<kbd>select location</kbd>) and a new screen appears. In this screen the user can select a new location for the search (by tapping on a map). 
Say the user opens this screen, selects `Munich` but then changes his mind and, instead of confirming `Munich`, presses the <kbd>Back</kbd> button. He's on the first screen again, `Berlin` still being the selected location. Now he opens the *"select location'* screen again.

Would he expect `Berlin` to be the pre-selection in that screen because he never really selected `Munich` or would he expect `Munich` to still be the selection because that was the state of the second screen when he left it?

I hope it's clear what I mean :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be clearer to keep the second screen as it is left. The application does not change something behind the back of the user. This way you also prevent the data loss which would occur when the user would press back by accident.